# Intermittent issue with ObjectContext in EF 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a very peculiar issue that only shows itself immediately following a Database rebuild.

If I blow away my database, repopulate, and immediately execute:

```
 dbContext.Employees.Where(expr).ToList()
```

I receive the following error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been
>   disposed and can no longer be used for
>   operations that require a connection.

However, if I blow away the database, repopulate, and immediately execute:

```
 dbContext.Employees.ToList()
```

It works just fine.

If I have not recently (on the same thread) blown away the and rebuild the Database, both statements execute just fine.  It is only after a DB Rebuild that I get the error.  Any ideas?

Note: the Employee class has no child classes.  It is comprised of only integers and strings.

Comment: Why do you blow away the database in the same thread? Is it unit test?

Comment: Good question.  Yes, I am running a series of unit tests.  We have it set up to blow away the DB if the data model has changed.  If the data model has not changed, the unit tests all complete without any problems.  However, if the model has changed, and it needs to blow away the DB, the "ToList" with the Where clause gives an error.